# need input for a .bat file appending lines of text(semi-working)

Tags: batch-file, append, dosbox

Preface: It's been awhile since I've created a batch file and this is my first time using this site so if 
I overlook or forget to do something just point it out and I'll fix it.

Today I decided to dive back into some dos games and I wanted to make a batch file to allow me to append three
lines of text, essentially the mount->c:->.exe lines that you typically write manually, to the [autoexec] section 
of the dosbox.conf.

After a day of tinkering I finally got the batchfile to work with a few games,warcraft2/DungeonMaster/LandsofLore,
the only problem I'm having now is that the code works fine for the three mentioned above but the other ones it doesn't 
even append to the dosbox.conf.

(after 'debugging' a bit,used warcraft1)
I've put pause commands after 'set/p input' and in the if statement for war1 also in the war1 label,beginning and end of it. the only pause that triggers is the one at 'set/p input' so the code is either overlooking the If statements or I don't know what I'm doing.

Any pointers on what I did wrong would be appreciated. 
TL:DR code works for warcraft2(input w),Lands of Lore(input l),dungeon master(input d) the other inputs seem to either exit right after input or cancel before it gets to the IF statement/s

```
 @echo off

REM ask is currently not used
:ask
REM asks for input
echo Which game would you like to play?
echo ___________________________________________________________________________________________
echo [w]arcraft 2 - w[a]rcraft1 - [c]ivilization - d[u]ne 2 - [d]ungeon master
echo [l]ands of lore - [o]regontrail - [s]im ant - Wol[f]3D 
echo -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

REM input variable
setlocal
SET /P INPUT=[]

REM check user input then go to selected game
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="w" (
    goto war2
)
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="d" (
    goto dungeon
)
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="l" (
    goto land
)
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="a"(
    goto war1
)
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="c"(
    goto civ
)
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="u"(
    goto dune2
)
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="o"(
    goto trail
)
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="s"(
    goto ant
)
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="f"(
    goto wolf
)

REM appends text to the end of dosbox.conf,after the [autoexec]
REM then starts dosbox and ends the file.
:war1
    ECHO mount -u c>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
    ECHO mount c f:\DOSGames\war1\  -label warcraft1>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
    ECHO c:>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
    ECHO WAR>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
 start F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\DOSBoxPortable.EXE
goto:EOF
:civ
    ECHO mount -u c>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
    ECHO mount c f:\DOSGames\civ\  -label Civ>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
    ECHO c:>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
    ECHO CIV>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
 start F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\DOSBoxPortable.EXE
goto:EOF
:dune2
    ECHO mount -u c>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
    ECHO mount c f:\DOSGames\dun2\  -label Dune 2>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
    ECHO c:>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
    ECHO DUNE2>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
 start F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\DOSBoxPortable.EXE
goto:EOF
:trail
    ECHO mount -u c>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
    ECHO mount c f:\DOSGames\oregontrail\  -label Oregon Trail>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
    ECHO c:>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
    ECHO OREGON>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
 start F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\DOSBoxPortable.EXE
goto:EOF
:ant
    ECHO mount -u c>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
    ECHO mount c f:\DOSGames\simant\  -label Sim Ant>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
    ECHO c:>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
    ECHO SIMANT>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
 start F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\DOSBoxPortable.EXE
goto:EOF
:wolf
    ECHO mount -u c>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
    ECHO mount c f:\DOSGames\WOLF3D\  -label Oregon Trail>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
    ECHO c:>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
    ECHO WOLFD3D>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
 start F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\DOSBoxPortable.EXE
goto:EOF
:war2
    ECHO mount -u c>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
    ECHO mount c f:\DOSGames\war2\war2\  -label warcraft2>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
    ECHO c:>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
    ECHO war2>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
 start F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\DOSBoxPortable.EXE
goto:EOF
:dungeon
    ECHO mount -u c>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf" 
    ECHO mount c f:\DOSGames\DungeonMaster\ -t cdrom -label DungeonMaster>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
    ECHO c:>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
    ECHO dm>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
 start F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\DOSBoxPortable.EXE
goto:EOF
:land   
    ECHO mount -u c>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
    ECHO mount c f:\DOSGames\LoL\ -label lands>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
    ECHO c:>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
    ECHO lands>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
 start F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\DOSBoxPortable.EXE
```

Comment: One problem I can see is with `ECHO mount c f:\DOSGames\dun2\  -label Dune 2>>...` the 2 here has special significance. When it appears immediately before the `>>` it means "append the standard error stream to the given file".

Comment: Oooo that is a massive derp, went back and put a space in between the 2 and >> though if that would still cause problems I can always switch the 2 to roman numerals.

Comment: The space should cure that particular issue. You may have other problems that I haven't been able to spot.

Comment: true that,I've got all the appending's working now. though i'll save the in-depth 'debugging' for tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You you ran the script from the command prompt instead of double-clicking it, you would see that you were getting a "The syntax of the command is incorrect" error.

This is because you are missing a space before the `(` in each of your `if` statements except for the ones for Warcraft 2, Dungeon Master, and Lands of Lore.

```
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="w" (
    goto war2
)
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="d" (
    goto dungeon
)
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="l" (
    goto land
)
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="a" (
    goto war1
)
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="c" (
    goto civ
)
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="u" (
    goto dune2
)
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="o" (
    goto trail
)
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="s" (
    goto ant
)
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="f" (
    goto wolf
)
```

You could also have avoided this by putting the `goto`s on the same line as the `if`s without the parentheses.

```
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="w" goto war2
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="d" goto dungeon
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="l" goto land
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="a" goto war1
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="c" goto civ
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="u" goto dune2
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="o" goto trail
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="s" goto ant
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="f" goto wolf
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a space between the input value trailing double quote and the open parenthesis in the lines that do not work.

However I'd suggest this change to make it easier to manage the code.

Use variables for the repeated entries and make a loop to go back to Ask as well as a Quit option.

```
@echo off
setlocal

:: ask is currently not used
:ask
:: asks for input
cls
echo Which game would you like to play?
echo ___________________________________________________________________________________________
echo [w]arcraft 2 - w[a]rcraft1 - [c]ivilization - d[u]ne 2 - [d]ungeon master
echo [l]ands of lore - [o]regontrail - [s]im ant - Wol[f]3D  - [Q]uit
echo -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

:: input variable
SET /P INPUT=[]

IF /I "%INPUT%"=="q" then Exit

set DosBoxConf="F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
set MountDrive=mount -u c
set MyDrive=C:

:: check user input then go to selected game
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="w" ( 
set MountCmd=mount c f:\DOSGames\war2\war2\  -label warcraft2
set RunCmd=WAR2
goto RunDosBox
) 
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="d" ( 
set MountCmd=mount c f:\DOSGames\DungeonMaster\ -t cdrom -label DungeonMaster
set RunCmd=DM
goto RunDosBox
) 
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="l" ( )
set MountCmd=mount c f:\DOSGames\LoL\ -label lands
set RunCmd=lands
goto RunDosBox
) 
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="a" ( 
set MountCmd=mount c f:\DOSGames\war1\  -label warcraft1
set RunCmd=WAR
goto RunDosBox
) 
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="c" ( 
set MountCmd=mount c f:\DOSGames\civ\  -label Civ
set RunCmd=CIV
goto RunDosBox
) 
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="u" ( 
set MountCmd=mount c f:\DOSGames\dun2\  -label Dune 2
set RunCmd=DUNE2
goto RunDosBox
) 
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="o" ( 
set MountCmd=mount c f:\DOSGames\oregontrail\  -label Oregon Trail
set RunCmd=OREGON
goto RunDosBox
) 
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="s" ( 
set MountCmd=mount c f:\DOSGames\simant\  -label Sim Ant
set RunCmd=SIMANT
goto RunDosBox
) 
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="f" ( 
set MountCmd=mount c f:\DOSGames\WOLF3D\  -label Wolf 3D
set RunCmd=WOLFD3D
goto RunDosBox
) 
:: back to ask if input didn't match a choice
goto ask

:RunDosBox
:: build the config and run DosBox
ECHO %MountDrive%>>%DosBoxConf%
ECHO %MountCmd%>>%DosBoxConf%
ECHO %MyDrive%>>%DosBoxConf%
ECHO %RunCmd%>>%DosBoxConf%
start F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\DOSBoxPortable.EXE
```

Also note that this line in your code has an incorrect tag for Oregon Trail but the section is for Wolf3D.

```
ECHO mount c f:\DOSGames\WOLF3D\  -label Oregon Trail>>"F:\Programs\DOSBoxPortable\Data\settings\dosbox.conf"
```

Comment: heh I was adding in my  .conf cleaner(a batch file that saves a clean version of the conf over the used conf, for when I want to play a different game.I eventually plan on adding in the finer details but for now it works and I really don't want to start editing it then create another problem. just saw your last comment.. xD yea I was copy/pasting the code then filling in the specifics will definitely go over it with a fine combed brush